# How to add header and footer in some specific components not in all. In Router V6 in React js

Tags: reactjs, router

**I want to add header in all components but not in Login Page.**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import {Routes} from "react-router";
import Checkout from './Checkout';
import Login from './Login';


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="app">
    <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/checkout" element={< Checkout />}>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/" element={ <Home/> }>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/login" element={< Login />}>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**In React Router v6 there are lots of changes are done but I don't understand how to do this. Please some one answer this question **

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import {Routes} from "react-router";
import Checkout from './Checkout';
import Login from './Login';


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="app">
    
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/checkout" element={<><Header />< Checkout /></>}>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/" element={ <><Header /><Home/> </>}>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/login" element={< Login />}>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

or in Header component:

```
if( window.location.pathname === "/login")
  return "";
else
 return (your_Header_render);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend walking through the [react router tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial), it's short covers a lot.

There is no more 'exact', and routes are nested. So, you match the top-level route and produce a `<PageWrapper />` or whatever you'd like to call it. In there, you can put `<Header /><Outlet /><Footer/>` where `<Outlet/>` is a react-router component that injects one of your other components based on what the route is.

Inside the `/` route, you designate `<Home/>` as the default route by using `index` and no `path`, and just other routes as you like, nesting things as deeply as you like.

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/" element={ <PageWrapper /> }>
    <Route index element={ <Home/> }>
    <Route path="/checkout" element={< Checkout />} />
    <Route path="/login" element={< Login />} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```